# find browser user is using in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

hi web2py newbie here how do i get information which browser user is using ..using web2py

i am trying below code

browser=request.env.http_user_agent

but giving me result like

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.60 Safari/534.24

but I am only using chrome here how do i get that?

---

thanks zoer that doesnot worked for me.

i was thinking to identify it using javascript and send to controller function
i also want identify operating system as well

i have found this way through which u can send values to controller
but i am not geting how to use it

$.post(CONTROLLER_URL, {'browser': chrome}, function 
HANDLER)) 
and will get this value in request.vars.browse

but i am geting how to use it..is anyone  know how to use $.post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do what Zaur has suggested assuming all you want to detect is Chrome. Otherwise you can check [httpagentparser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpagentparser/)

Answer (score 3):

You will always get results like that, because it's how the browsers' engines are identified (see [user-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-agent) article on Wikipedia).

You have to manually parse the user-agent string, something like:

```
if 'Chrome' in browser:
  users_browser = 'chrome'
```

Answer (score 3):

In new versions 2.* every request includes browser info by calling `request.user_agent()`

That function uses:

```
from gluon.contrib import user_agent_parser
```

Example info:

```
browser :   name    :   Firefox
        version :   15.0.1
is_mobile:  False
is_tablet:  False
os  :   name    :   Windows
        version :   NT 6.1
```

This info is always in `session._user_agent`

So you can check:

```
if session._user_agent['browser']['name']=='Chrome':
    ...your code
```

Comment: you probably should not use `_user_agent` which is likely an implementation detail.  Instead you could do: `if request.user_agent()['browser']['name'] == 'Chrome'`